# How to extract everything between two patterns (using sed?)?

Tags: regex, sed

I am running a curl command (plus a grep) and I want to extract everything between two patterns from the output.

Here's an example output from the curl (and grep):

```
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 15848    0 15848    0     0   708k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  736k
</message><refDesc>PULL Task 8c4d1a50-3e05-4b58-8d1a-503e057b586d 4_Place_All_Users_In_Inactive</refDesc><refKey>8c4d1a50-3e05-4b58-8d1a-503e057b586d</refKey><status>SUCCESS</status></syncope21:exec><syncope21:exec xmlns:syncope21="http://syncope.apache.org/2.1"><end>2020-01-22T01:13:44.512Z</end><start>2020-01-22T01:13:44.506Z</start><jobType>TASK</jobType><key>40e64a39-47e7-4428-a64a-3947e7c4286b</key><message>Users [created/failures]: 0/0 [updated/failures]: 0/0 [deleted/failures]: 0/0 [no operation/ignored]: 0/0
```

and I want to extract everything between the `</message>` and the `</start>`, e.g., from the above, I want:

`</message><refDesc>PULL Task 8c4d1a50-3e05-4b58-8d1a-503e057b586d 4_Place_All_Users_In_Inactive</refDesc><refKey>8c4d1a50-3e05-4b58-8d1a-503e057b586d</refKey><status>SUCCESS</status></syncope21:exec><syncope21:exec xmlns:syncope21="http://syncope.apache.org/2.1"><end>2020-01-22T01:13:44.512Z</end><start>2020-01-22T01:13:44.506Z</start>`

I have tried following:

`curl -X GET ...." | grep xxxxxxx | sed -n -e '/<\/message>/,/<\/start>/p'`

but it doesn't seem to be working (it seems to be returning the entire output, rather than extracting.

Can someone tell me how to do that?

Thanks!

Jim

Answer (score 0):

***`awk` solutions:*** Could you please try following,if data is present in an Input_file.

```
awk 'match($0,/<\/message>.*<start>/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' Input_file
```

***OR with `curl` use it like :***

```
curl -X GET ...." | awk '{gsub(/\r/,"")} match($0,/<\/message>.*<start>/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'
```

---

---

***`sed` solutions:*** OR with GNU `sed`'s `-z` option:

```
sed -z 's/.*\(<\/message>.*<start>\).*/\1\n/' Input_file
```

***with `curl` + `sed`:***

```
curl -X GET ...." | sed -z 's/\r//g;s/.*\(<\/message>.*<start>\).*/\1\n/'
```

With shown sample output will be as follows.

`</message><refDesc>PULL Task 8c4d1a50-3e05-4b58-8d1a-503e057b586d 4_Place_All_Users_In_Inactive</refDesc><refKey>8c4d1a50-3e05-4b58-8d1a-503e057b586d</refKey><status>SUCCESS</status></syncope21:exec><syncope21:exec xmlns:syncope21="http://syncope.apache.org/2.1"><end>2020-01-22T01:13:44.512Z</end><start>`

Comment: your last (curl * sed) comes close, but it does not extract the value of the ```<start>``` element?  Jim

Comment: @user555303, Could you please do lemme know if these solutions helped you?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below using `GNU sed`:

`sed -E -n 's#(^</message>.*</start>).*#\1#p'`

so, basically, your command would look like:

`curl -X GET ...." | grep xxxxxxx | sed -E -n 's#(^</message>.*</start>).*#\1#p'`

Comment: Ahh - ok I think I see the problem (my mistake).  I hadn't realized that the TWO lines (similar format but different information).  So your sed command DOES work, but it is processing both lines (and looks like some cases have more than 2 lines even).  If I might ask, how can I change the sed so that it just processes the first line and outputs just that?

Comment: @user555303: well. in that case you pipe the `sed` command to `|head -n 1 ` to get the first line of the output. Also, instead of using `grep`, you can search the required string using `sed`: `curl -X GET ...." | sed -E -n '/xxxxxxx/ s#(^</message>.*</start>).*#\1#p' |head -n 1`  .

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/\n/!{s/<\/message>/\n&/;s/<\/start>/&\n/};/^<\/message>/P;D' file
```

If a line has not already been amended, insert a newline before `</message>` and after `</start>` and print only that part of the line.