# How to extract only first occurrence of a match between two patterns

Tags: regex, sed

This is followup, but slightly different problem to another question that I posted earlier at:

[How to extract everything between two patterns (using sed?)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59851674/how-to-extract-everything-between-two-patterns-using-sed)

During testing, I have also found that in some cases, more than one of the records are not only in a single file, but also all the records are just together in a single line, with no newlines between them, and when I run the sed command on that one combined line, it seems like it will find a match, but the match, but it is not the first match (I don't actually know why it is matching the one that it is finding).

I know that the first "line" is also the most recent record, so I would like to perform a sed type match to extract the  time from the first record, but only from the first record.

Here a snippet to illustrate what I tried to describe above:

```
UPDATE SUCCESS (key/name): 7c061313-9cbd-4bd1-8613-139cbd2bd1da/snctest38
UPDATE SUCCESS (key/name): 7ebab268-05dc-4110-bab2-6805dc2110f6/snctest4
UPDATE SUCCESS (key/name): 8ef15385-3d23-40e9-b153-853d2310e9fd/snctest5
UPDATE SUCCESS (key/name): 978bf8b5-b4aa-4cd4-8bf8-b5b4aaacd4b6/snctest6
UPDATE SUCCESS (key/name): 34f28da7-1311-4cb7-b28d-a713116cb77d/snctest7
UPDATE SUCCESS (key/name): 7be77991-4c73-4c35-a779-914c73ec359a/snctest8
</message><refDesc>PUSH Task 0a64cff0-b826-420b-a4cf-f0b826420bae 2_ldapadd</refDesc><refKey>0a64cff0-b826-420b-a4cf-f0b826420bae</refKey><status>SUCCESS</status></syncope21:exec><syncope21:exec xmlns:syncope21="http://syncope.apache.org/2.1"><end>2020-01-22T05:36:59.649Z</end><start>2020-01-22T05:36:59.639Z</start><jobType>TASK</jobType><key>c4a0f6fa-109e-4a25-a0f6-fa109e5a2505</key><refDesc>PROPAGATION Task 3a2457ef-556b-4f39-a457-ef556b6f3921 d228de62-2918-46fe-960a-a193c3bfa0c3</refDesc><refKey>3a2457ef-556b-4f39-a457-ef556b6f3921</refKey><status>SUCCESS</status></syncope21:exec><syncope21:exec xmlns:syncope21="http://syncope.apache.org/2.1"><end>2020-01-22T05:36:59.567Z</end><start>2020-01-22T05:36:59.558Z</start><jobType>TASK</jobType><key>e9defd1b-966f-4830-9efd-1b966f183008</key><refDesc>PROPAGATION Task a47fee5a-fea3-4422-bfee-5afea3e422c5 e7394424-a4b7-41fe-90a1-46e3b309e6f2</refDesc><refKey>a47fee5a-fea3-4422-bfee-5afea3e422c5</refKey><status>SUCCESS</status></syncope21:exec><syncope21:exec xmlns:syncope21="http://syncope.apache.org/2.1"><end>2020-01-22T05:36:59.485Z</end><start>2020-01-22T05:36:59.476Z</start><jobType>TASK</jobType><key>52ab4c49-e28d-49d3-ab4c-49e28d39d38e</key><refDesc>PROPAGATION Task 437e3eb4-487f-471c-be3e-b4487f971cdf 11f95ec1-ac16-4344-8741-ae362ec4b357</refDesc><refKey>437e3eb4-487f-471c-be3e-b4487f971cdf</refKey><status>SUCCESS</status></syncope21:exec><syncope21:exec xmlns:syncope21="http://syncope.apache.org/2.1"><end>2020-01-22T05:36:59.394Z</end><start>2020-01-22T05:36:59.385Z</start><jobType>TASK</jobType><key>17c947c9-eb8d-4222-8947-c9eb8d622288</key><refDesc>PROPAGATION Task 67956b5a-86a2-4f0c-956b-5a86a24f0c35 d7df1a03-a7f7-4a7b-8cab-d098852de2f3</refDesc><refKey>67956b5a-86a2-4f0c-956b-5a86a24f0c35</refKey><status>SUCCESS</status></syncope21:exec><syncope21:exec xmlns:syncope21="http://syncope.apache.org/2.1"><end>2020-01-22T05:36:59.312Z</end><start>2020-01-22T05:36:59.302Z</start><jobType>TASK</jobType><key>42a7e05a-5ed2-438c-a7e0-5a5ed2e38c64</key><refDesc>PROPAGATION Task d3d6026d-f4fd-4c64-9602-6df4fd1c6455 321861ed-3ede-4981-a6cc-cc193662a652</refDesc><refKey>d3d6026d-f4fd-4c64-9602-6df4fd1c6455</refKey><status>SUCCESS</status></syncope21:exec><syncope21:exec xmlns:syncope21="http://syncope.apache.org/2.1"><end>2020-01-22T05:36:59.226Z</end><start>2020-01-22T05:36:59.216Z</start><jobType>TASK</jobType><key>09e1767b-e243-47ea-a176-7be243a7eabd</key><refDesc>PROPAGATION Task 3dd00b2e-e0ab-43c8-900b-2ee0ab43c8de a3b19123-38de-4702-907a-11d7a14d7a64</refDesc><refKey>3dd00b2e-e0ab-43c8-900b-2ee0ab43c8de</refKey><status>SUCCESS</status></syncope21:exec><syncope21:exec xmlns:syncope21="http://syncope.apache.org/2.1"><end>2020-01-22T05:36:59.145Z</end><start>2020-01-22T05:36:59.135Z</start><jobType>TASK</jobType><key>b13e32e2-e361-4175-be32-e2e361917501</key><refDesc>PROPAGATION Task de139a01-fb49-4ea5-939a-01fb49cea584 2a6b616b-5319-423c-9d4a-47157dfe2cbc</refDesc><refKey>de139a01-fb49-4ea5-939a-01fb49cea584</refKey><status>SUCCESS</status></syncope21:exec><syncope21:exec xmlns:syncope21="http://syncope.apache.org/2.1"><end>2020-01-22T05:36:59.064Z</end><start>2020-01-22T05:36:59.054Z</start><jobType>TASK</jobType><key>cb24ebcd-6448-444b-a4eb-cd6448944bbc</key><refDesc>PROPAGATION Task aa947230-0cb2-40d2-9472-300cb270d230 0fade8e2-cfdf-4dc4-87ba-6d1352d32840</refDesc><refKey>aa947230-0cb2-40d2-9472-300cb270d230</refKey><status>SUCCESS</status></syncope21:exec><syncope21:exec xmlns:syncope21="http://syncope.apache.org/2.1"><end>2020-01-22T05:36:58.983Z</end><start>2020-01-22T05:36:58.973Z</start><jobType>TASK</jobType><key>04897743-9db6-496f-8977-439db6596fab</key><refDesc>PROPAGATION Task bc3ae42c-701e-4258-bae4-2c701e3258cc 98f9e4de-0e86-447d-9ffa-c87c96a947ca</refDesc><refKey>bc3ae42c-701e-4258-bae4-2c701e3258cc</refKey><status>SUCCESS</status></syncope21:exec><syncope21:exec xmlns:syncope21="http://syncope.apache.org/2.1"><end>2020-01-22T05:36:58.901Z</end><start>2020-01-22T05:36:58.891Z</start><jobType>TASK</jobType><key>999bab8f-9e64-4f53-9bab-8f9e64df5320</key><refDesc>PROPAGATION Task 15371c79-1ac0-4282-b71c-791ac0e28230 fbdf2574-5e7d-4e97-af94-e4d6169fc02b</refDesc><refKey>15371c79-1ac0-4282-b71c-791ac0e28230</refKey><status>SUCCESS</status></syncope21:exec><syncope21:exec xmlns:syncope21="http://syncope.apache.org/2.1"><end>2020-01-22T05:36:58.819Z</end><start>2020-01-22T05:36:58.810Z</start><jobType>TASK</jobType><key>81e907f6-d358-42b9-a907-f6d358e2b997</key><refDesc>PROPAGATION Task 5401a5d8-0407-4c2f-81a5-d804071c2fd0 81679e82-7006-4a2b-8914-f76fea587cec</refDesc><refKey>5401a5d8-0407-4c2f-81a5-d804071c2fd0</refKey><status>SUCCESS</status></syncope21:exec><syncope21:exec xmlns:syncope21="http://syncope.apache.org/2.1"><end>2020-01-22T05:36:58.738Z</end><start>2020-01-22T05:36:58.728Z</start><jobType>TASK</jobType><key>a6b42457-4b18-4dcc-b424-574b180dcc51</key><refDesc>PROPAGATION Task 90cc1ef6-5b5a-4f4d-8c1e-f65b5acf4d16 42ac4e4e-71e8-4cfb-8c2e-ceced4cdf029</refDesc><refKey>90cc1ef6-5b5a-4f4d-8c1e-f65b5acf4d16</refKey><status>SUCCESS</status></syncope21:exec><syncope21:exec xmlns:syncope21="http://syncope.apache.org/2.1"><end>2020-01-22T05:36:58.655Z</end><start>2020-01-22T05:36:58.645Z</start><jobType>TASK</jobType><key>8aba0dc9-3df4-4398-ba0d-c93df453989c</key><refDesc>PROPAGATION Task a074cbf2-de6c-4c15-b4cb-f2de6c4c15cd 6e37c044-5aa2-45e6-9626-27e0b2f52038</refDesc><refKey>a074cbf2-de6c-4c15-b4cb-f2de6c4c15cd</refKey><status>SUCCESS</status></syncope21:exec><syncope21:exec xmlns:syncope21="http://syncope.apache.org/2.1"><end>2020-01-22T05:36:58.571Z</end><start>2020-01-22T05:36:58.561Z</start><jobType>TASK</jobType><key>723f4400-49cd-4507-bf44-0049cdd507a1</key><refDesc>PROPAGATION Task cb87d842-2849-45ca-87d8-422849e5caa8 8bcd6de0-9e6f-4261-89b3-e3d56400f7af</refDesc><refKey>cb87d842-2849-45ca-87d8-422849e5caa8</refKey><status>SUCCESS</status></syncope21:exec><syncope21:exec xmlns:syncope21="http://syncope.apache.org/2.1"><end>2020-01-22T05:36:58.485Z</end><start>2020-01-22T05:36:58.474Z</start><jobType>TASK</jobType><key>a0b82ca0-8e2e-4b05-b82c-a08e2e8b0548</key><refDesc>PROPAGATION Task 828178dd-c1c8-4668-8178-ddc1c80668e7 d91141d7-2fd4-4fef-adc4-79cb81f1560b</refDesc><refKey>828178dd-c1c8-4668-8178-ddc1c80668e7</refKey><status>SUCCESS</status></syncope21:exec><syncope21:exec xmlns:syncope21="http://syncope.apache.org/2.1"><end>2020-01-22T05:36:58.401Z</end><start>2020-01-22T05:36:58.391Z</start><jobType>TASK</jobType><key>0c2f6210-f095-427c-af62-10f095927c09</key><refDesc>PROPAGATION Task 1b9cb7c6-7b51-4f4a-9cb7-c67b51bf4ae9 440fa8f9-ecd4-4053-9b07-fd22ed49b139</refDesc><refKey>1b9cb7c6-7b51-4f4a-9cb7-c67b51bf4ae9</refKey><status>SUCCESS</status></syncope21:exec><syncope21:exec xmlns:syncope21="http://syncope.apache.org/2.1"><end>2020-01-22T05:36:58.319Z</end><start>2020-01-22T05:36:58.309Z</start><jobType>TASK</jobType><key>77b14d6c-5be6-40e0-b14d-6c5be6f0e00b</key><refDesc>PROPAGATION Task 289a014d-3646-456d-9a01-4d3646356dd0 59fd7993-2737-46d6-8c0e-a26f8f02e234</refDesc><refKey>289a014d-3646-456d-9a01-4d3646356dd0</refKey><status>SUCCESS</status></syncope21:exec><syncope21:exec xmlns:syncope21="http://syncope.apache.org/2.1"><end>2020-01-22T05:36:58.237Z</end><start>2020-01-22T05:36:58.227Z</start><jobType>TASK</jobType><key>0f59fe8b-f057-4039-99fe-8bf057d0394e</key><refDesc>PROPAGATION Task 3f9f7751-787f-4dd2-9f77-51787fedd2bf 106abcb7-a5f0-4333-8e9e-0a81e84af904</refDesc><refKey>3f9f7751-787f-4dd2-9f77-51787fedd2bf</refKey><status>SUCCESS</status></syncope21:exec><syncope21:exec xmlns:syncope21="http://syncope.apache.org/2.1"><end>2020-01-22T05:36:58.154Z</end><start>2020-01-22T05:36:58.143Z</start><jobType>TASK</jobType><key>a5c44fb7-2b39-4e22-844f-b72b39de22ff</key><refDesc>PROPAGATION Task d9f712ea-d3a7-44a0-b712-ead3a784a05e efb1c4ca-6598-4cce-9aef-c749bf18e10b</refDesc><refKey>d9f712ea-d3a7-44a0-b712-ead3a784a05e</refKey><status>SUCCESS</status></syncope21:exec><syncope21:exec xmlns:syncope21="http://syncope.apache.org/2.1"><end>2020-01-22T05:36:58.066Z</end><start>2020-01-22T05:36:58.056Z</start><jobType>TASK</jobType><key>a9c2b65a-2cc6-4e70-82b6-5a2cc6fe7083</key><refDesc>PROPAGATION Task e504ad04-6afc-4880-84ad-046afcd8806c a025af4f-b7b8-4d90-917c-d3ff79d13780</refDesc><refKey>e504ad04-6afc-4880-84ad-046afcd8806c</refKey><status>SUCCESS</status></syncope21:exec><syncope21:exec xmlns:syncope21="http://syncope.apache.org/2.1"><end>2020-01-22T05:36:57.985Z</end><start>2020-01-22T05:36:57.975Z</start><jobType>TASK</jobType><key>a433e0da-71e5-4957-b3e0-da71e5d95744</key><refDesc>PROPAGATION Task 30597ec2-8cea-4744-997e-c28cea47446a 101d544c-5355-436b-9e93-aebcbf3b5da4</refDesc><refKey>30597ec2-8cea-4744-997e-c28cea47446a</refKey><status>SUCCESS</status></syncope21:exec><syncope21:exec xmlns:syncope21="http://syncope.apache.org/2.1"><end>2020-01-22T05:36:57.902Z</end><start>2020-01-22T05:36:57.891Z</start><jobType>TASK</jobType><key>a854c35a-291f-43c8-94c3-5a291fb3c891</key><refDesc>PROPAGATION Task 58ed721f-0b25-4a39-ad72-1f0b255a39c6 404aa838-b14a-40fd-8e6f-5a0522cfcce8</refDesc><refKey>58ed721f-0b25-4a39-ad72-1f0b255a39c6</refKey><status>SUCCESS</status></syncope21:exec><syncope21:exec xmlns:syncope21="http://syncope.apache.org/2.1"><end>2020-01-22T05:36:57.817Z</end><start>2020-01-22T05:36:57.807Z</start><jobType>TASK</jobType><key>19a4823a-b57e-4a51-a482-3ab57eaa5172</key><refDesc>PROPAGATION Task 9d0c6898-185b-4eac-8c68-98185b9eacb8 2b6dc9a1-8cf9-4b8c-a597-b1fc4ecd9b72</refDesc><refKey>9d0c6898-185b-4eac-8c68-98185b9eacb8</refKey><status>SUCCESS</status></syncope21:exec><syncope21:exec xmlns:syncope21="http://syncope.apache.org/2.1"><end>2020-01-22T05:36:57.728Z</end><start>2020-01-22T05:36:57.717Z</start><jobType>TASK</jobType><key>f5b0ccb5-304f-40d2-b0cc-b5304f30d21e</key><refDesc>PROPAGATION Task 98b26cc8-0ff9-487b-b26c-c80ff9487b59 ac164590-3e66-42a5-b7d7-c001fa641a24</refDesc><refKey>98b26cc8-0ff9-487b-b26c-c80ff9487b59</refKey><status>SUCCESS</status></syncope21:exec></syncope21:execs>
```

As you can see there are apparently multiple "lines" glommed together into one large line.

So how can some of the sed commands that were suggested in that previous thread be modified to match and extract just the first match?

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: @Yunnosch I like the one that I posted better, since it has an image showing what to do, since I believe that usually if you don't upvote/accept you don't bother reading the "rules" anyway. I know a lot of people who don't read manuals (well, then again who does) to _whatever_ but watch related _whatever_ used in Youtube. Combining your link with a couple of more images would be perfect for all groups.

Comment: @JamesBrown Fair enough.

Answer (score -1):

If I'm reading your question right (and this is not easy given its dependence on other questions), you just want the shorted match between two given regexes (which are themselves just strings): `<\/messages>` and `<\/start>`.

```sh
sed '/<\/message>.*<\/start>/ { s:^.*</message>:</message>:; s:</start>.*$:</start>: }'
```

This uses POSIX `sed` since you have not specified that you're using GNU (e.g. via a Linux distribution). First, we check to ensure the line has a match. If it does, remove everything before the final `</message>` and then remove everything after the first `</start>`.

This would be more elegant with GNU (or BSD) `sed` since you can use backreferences to retain those tags:

```sh
sed -E '/<\/message>.*<\/start>/ { s:^.*(</message>):\1:; s:(</start>).*$:\1: }'
```

Personally, I'd use GNU grep (assuming it's compiled with libpcre to support `-P`):

```sh
grep -Po '</message>.*?</start>'
```

This will only display the matching text of the shortest match between those two given strings.